# Selenium Webdriver - Click() method fails with IE driver

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-iedriver

I'm using the IE driver with `IE11`,
For some elements `Click` method will only select a element,
it wont do the action of the `Click()`. 
With `ChromeDriver` and `FirefoxDriver` same script is working fine.

I've set driver capabilities as below

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS, false);
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING, false);
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, false);
```

I found some solutions on following links but still facing same issue.

[Selenium WebDriver Click issue in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148274/selenium-webdriver-click-issue-in-internet-explorer)

[Selenium WebDriver on IE 9, on clicking, links are flashing as if some click event was not completely handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958314/selenium-webdriver-on-ie-9-on-clicking-links-are-flashing-as-if-some-click-eve)

[Selenium 2.0b3 IE WebDriver, Click not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574802/selenium-2-0b3-ie-webdriver-click-not-firing)

Comment: Which `iedriverserver` are you using `64-bit` or `32-bit`?? and what happened when you are going to click using `WebElement.click()`?? is there any exception??

Comment: I'm using 32-bit driver , and no exceptions are found when i use element.click()

Comment: Is this element manually clickable correctly at IE browser??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur i'm using 64-bit OS , but 64-bit IEdriver was very slow and i found some solutions related to that so , currently using 32-bit driver , also tried 64-bit driver but i faced same issue.

Comment: yes, it's clickable

Comment: You are using `32-bit`, that is good, did you tried using `WebDriverWait` to wait until this visible and clickable?? or could you share your code that how to perform click on it???

Comment: @SaurabhGaur while debugging i found that element was not clickable and issue was solved by setting IE capability `caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, false);`but still click() doesn't work while executing script.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur yes, element is clickable and isenable() method also return true.

Comment: Then it hard to say why is it not clickable on IE, may be its designing issue, try once using `Actions` class as `Actions::moveToElement(yourElement).click().perform();`

Comment: I've already tried that.

Comment: Then you can also try as an alternate solution using `JavascriptExecutor` as `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].cli‌​ck()", yourElement);`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say why is it not clickable on `IE`, may be its designing issue.

If you have tried all possibility, but nothing get success try using `JavascriptExecutor` as an alternate solution as below :-

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].cli‌​ck()", yourElement);
```

**Note** :- The `JavaScript` injection `HTMLElement.click()` shouldn't be used in a testing context. It defeats the purpose of the test. First because it doesn't generate all the events like a real `click (focus, blur, mousedown, mouseup...)` and second because it doesn't guarantee that a real user can interact with the element. But to get rid from this issues you can consider it as an alternate solution.

Comment: I'm able to click using JavascriptExecutor but, using this way i have to write separate click method , Because i  think using JavascriptExecutor for each click is not a good way.

Comment: Yes you are right you should create separate click method as `clickByJs()`..:)